# Python pandas - Grouping rows to sum integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

[image: Table being assessed]

I am trying to get the annual passenger trips between City1 and City2 each year (this data is monthly). As the DistanceKm is unique I have tried to use a groupby DistanceKm, however the output is just DistanceKm and Passenger Trips. Is there a better way to group by column1 and column 2 and sum the passenger trips at the same time?

```
    import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df[['DistanceKm','City1', 'City2', 'PassengerTrips']]
df = df.groupby('DistanceKm').sum()
df = df.sort_values('PassengerTrips', ascending =False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby(['City1', 'City2']).sum('PassengerTrips')
```